# Bit rate and sample rate for ogv movie to be played in rpg maker vx ace

Tags: audio, codec, bitrate, sample-rate

I've made a movie for RPG Maker XV ace with just music in the background.
The program only allows .ogv movies (OGG, THEORA) to be played. I have no problem with the video quality, however, the sound is distorted and "jumps"
(like when we were playing records in the '90s..) when there are high pitched or reverberating instruments.

The following are my settings for the movie output:

Container: OGG

Video Codec: Theora

Audio Codec: Vorbis

Bit rate: 160 (16 bit)

Sample rate: 44100 (44.1 kHz)

System: Windows 10

Video Editor: Blender 2.79

The .ogg audio files are perfect when played in RPG Maker Ace by themselves just as audio files. The problem only exists with the audio in .ogv movies.

I have already tried increasing the bit rate and the frame rate but to no avail.

Does anyone know the standard audio requirements for audio in movies for RPG Maker Ace?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I actually disobeyed what RPG Maker suggests in their help menu and made some changes as follow:

CONTAINER: OGG

VIDEO CODEC: H.264

OUTPUT QUALITY: CONSTANT BIT RATE (This is very important)

ENCODING SPEED: Medium

AUDIO CODEC: VORBIS

BIT RATE: 200

FRAME RATE: 48000

Now it works like a charm!